# Как в react определить массив в конструкторе одного класса, а обратиться к нему в другом классе?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я хочу опредеить массив в 1 классе, а перебрать его методом map и вывести в другом классе.
1 класс. Пример массива [1,2,3,4]

2 класс. 
`{myawesomearray.map((item, index) => <li key={index}>{item}</li>)}`

Comment: Используйте пропсы не за чем писать уродливый трудно поддерживаемый код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передача данных с одного компонента в другой - это база React.
1. С помощью props. https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html
Когда объявляете в родительском компонента дочерний, то передаете в его параметры этот массив

```
<NewCopmponent array={array} /> //передали параметры
```

Теперь используем:

```
class NewComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Привет, {this.props.array}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Также, параметры можно передавать с помощью Контекста
https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/context.html

и с помощью библиотеки Redux или хука useReducer + useContext, но это уже если неудобно через пропсы или много компонентов прокладок.